# Обработка exec() в PHP

Tags: php, python, exec

Необходимо запустить python скрипт из php.
Использую следующий код

```
$python =  exec('python bla.py');
echo "Python is printing: " .  $python;
```

Если python-файл содержит относительно простой код, вроде print(123) то все работает прекрасно, однако если код более сложный, то если поставить print(123) после блока import переменная $python пустая? Как это понять?

---

К сожалению ситуация не меняется. Попробуйте записать в bla.py

```
import requests
print(123)
```

Это python 2.7
Вывода в exec не будет

---

Проблема решена. Код был некорректный, поэтому была ошибка. Соответственно помогло 2>&1

Answer (score 1):

exec возвращает последнюю строку из результата работы команды, а не весь вывод.

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php

лучше сделай так:

```
$python = [];
exec('python bla.py', $python);
echo "Python is printing: " . implode(PHP_EOL, $python);
```

Comment: не работает к сожалению(